# How to make distinct join in SQLAlchemy with now Foreign Key?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two models in SQLAlchemy:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    common = Column(Integer)
    text = Column(String)

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    common = Column(Integer)
    url = Column(String)
```

There are no foreign keys between these two tables and I need to make common is common attribute of both tables. I need to generate SQLALchemy query, that selects all texts from table A that do not have corresponding common value in table B, or for that row `url == None`. Is there any simple query to achieve this using SQLAlchemy session?

Comment: Well I can make single query that selects all distinct common atributes from table B which have non null url, and then select distict A's that has commons not in first one. No idea hw to integrate into single query tho

Comment: basically the answer from Tohmaxxx would be good example of what I am trying to achieve with single query :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want A for which no B exists that has a non NULL url:

```
In [72]: session.query(A.text).\
    ...:     filter(~exists().where(and_(B.common == A.common,
    ...:                                 B.url != None)))
    ...:                                 
Out[72]: <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query at 0x7f50131ce2b0>

In [73]: print(_)
SELECT a.text AS a_text 
FROM a 
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM b 
WHERE b.common = a.common AND b.url IS NOT NULL))
```

The same using a LEFT JOIN:

```
In [76]: session.query(A.text).\
    ...:     outerjoin(B, and_(B.common == A.common,
    ...:                       B.url != None)).\
    ...:     filter(B.id == None)
    ...:                       
Out[76]: <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query at 0x7f5012f8d1d0>

In [77]: print(_)
SELECT a.text AS a_text 
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.common = a.common AND b.url IS NOT NULL 
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

q is not exactly clear, maybe some variation on this:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_

class User(db.Model):
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    common = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)

class Dept(db.Model):
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    common = Column(Integer)
    url = Column(String)


user1 = User(common=1)
user2 = User(common=2)
user3 = User(common=0)
dept1  = Dept( common = 0 )
dept2  = Dept( common = 1 )
dept3  = Dept( common = 3 )
dept3  = Dept( common = 4 )


common = db.session.query(User.common).distinct()
result = db.session.query(Dept).filter(Dept.common.notin_(common))
print([ r.common for r in result.all()] )
### filter dept.url:
result = db.session.query(Dept).filter(or_(Dept.common.notin_(common), Dept.url == 'xx'))
```

output>> [3, 4]

Comment: Yes this is basically how I got it right now,  but I wonder if there is possibility to do that as single select